# How to order the PHP output in an email?

Tags: php

I've created a web site and I'm using [this link](https://www.formget.com/how-to-create-pop-up-contact-form-using-javascript/) for a JS pop up form to be emailed using PHP.

I also used the code from [here](https://www.formget.com/send-an-email-on-form-submission-using-php/) and everything works except for a couple things. When I don't remove some variables, the order of information is out of place when it emails.

And when I keep all the variables, I get the following error in a log and nothing sends until I remove them:

> PHP Warning:  mail() expects at most 5 parameters, 7 given in xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/quote.php on line 41

Below is the code where the error is coming from:

```
else{
$Company = $_POST['company'];
$Email = $_POST['vemail'];
$Name = $_POST['name'];
$Number = $_POST['number'];
$Info = $_POST['info'];
$headers = 'From:'. $email2 . "\r\n"; // Sender's Email
$headers .= 'Cc:'. $email2 . "\r\n"; // Carbon copy to Sender
// Message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
// $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
// Send Mail By PHP Mail Function
mail("info@bvcdenver.com", $Company, $Email, $Name, $Number, $Info, $headers);
echo "Your quote request has been sent successfuly ! Thank you for your interst. You are being redirected back to xxxxxxxxxxxx in 5 seconds.";
}
```

How can I send all the variable? Order won't matter if I can get them all to send.

Note: I don't have a lot of scripting experience. This site is created using only HTML/CSS and these PHP and JS sections. So ideally I'd like to not change the entire site.

Answer (score 2):

You need to proper use the php mail function() as it is stated here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php.

The max number of parameters is 5:
- TO ( in your case: "info@bvcdenver.com" )
- SUBJECT ( in your case: $Company )
- MESSAGE ( in your case: $Email )
the last 2 are additional headers and additional parameters.

If you want to send all the data  "email, name, number and info" you should organize a string/text variable and put it on the 3rd place

like:
$message = $Email . " - " . $Name . " - " . $Number . " - " . $Info;
mail("info@bvcdenver.com", $company, $message, $headers);

This should do the work and you can customize the message numbers how you want, with html or raw new lines, and get a proper template.

Comment: I'll give this a shot. Thank you

Comment: I can't up-vote yet so I wanted to say this works. Thank you!

Comment: Glad that it helped you

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';//pass every variable into message
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```